# Path expected for join error JPA and named_queries xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting really confused with JPA and Hibernate with this error.

Here's the Stack exception

```
2012-08-07 03:55:04,277 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] (HDScanner)  Path expected for join!
2012-08-07 03:55:04,299 ERROR [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] (HDScanner) Error in named query: getTotalCallReportsFromQuarter
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [care.quarter], unexpected token [care] [SELECT count(noOfCallReports) FROM com.business.model.base.CareCallReport JOIN Relationships with CareCallReport.clientAccountNo=Relationships.clientAccountNo where UID = :UID and care.quarter = :quarter and care.year = :year]
```

Here's the 2 entities I planned to join:

```
CareCallReport.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARE_CALLREPORT")
public class ICareCallReport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ClientAccountNo", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private String clientAccountNo;

    @Column(name = "NoOfCallReports", nullable = false, length = 11)
    private int noOfCallReports;

    @Column(name = "Quarter", nullable = false, length = 11)
    private int quarter;

    @Column(name = "QtrYear", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private int year;

    ... Getters and Setters
```

And the other entity

```
ITRelationships.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "IT_RELATIONSHIPS")
public class ITRelationships implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ClientID",nullable = false, length = 7)
    private String clientID;

    @Column(name = "ClientAccountNo", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private String clientAccountNo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UID", nullable = false, length = 6)
    private String UID;

    @Column(name = "Quarter", nullable = false, length = 11)
    private int quarter;

    @Column(name = "QtrYear", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private int year;

    Getters and Setters
```

The JQL Method I wrote out was as such:

```
<access>FIELD</access>
<named-query name="getTotalCallReportsFromQuarter">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT count(noOfCallReports)
        FROM CareCallReport JOIN ITRelationships
        with CareCallReport.clientAccountNo = ITRelationships.clientAccountNo
        where UID = :uid
            and care.quarter = :quarter
            and care.year = :year
        ]]> 
    </query>
</named-query>
```

What did I do wrong? This is my first time I've ever touched on JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to use the alias in the query.

But again I just want to explain it a little more. With JPA/Hibernate you dont just map a Table in DB to a POJO (Entity), you map relation-ships also.

If I understand it right there is a one-to-one relation from IT_RELATIONSHIPS to CARE_CALLREPORT. In Object-Oriented terms ITRelationships has a reference to ICareCallReport.

Also ClientAccountNo is not actually a property of IT_RELATIONSHIPS entity, it is just a reference to CARE_CALLREPORT entity.

```
ITRelationships.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "IT_RELATIONSHIPS")
public class ITRelationships implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ClientID",nullable = false, length = 7)
    private String clientID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ClientAccountNo")
    private ICareCallReport careCallReport;

    ....
```

And now the query becomes much simpler. Remember this is not SQL, this is object query.

```
    <named-query name="getTotalCallReportsFromQuarter">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT itr.careCallReport.noOfCallReports
        FROM ITRelationships itr
        where itr.UID = :uid
            and itr.careCallReport.quarter = :quarter
            and itr.careCallReport.year = :year
        ]]> 
    </query>
    </named-query>
```

Answer (score 3):

You use an alias in your query (`icare`) without having defined it. Moreover, a join is only possible if you have an association (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany) between the entities. Assuming you don't have any, the query should be

```
SELECT count(care.noOfCallReports)
    FROM CareCallReport care, ITRelationships relationship
    where relationship.UID = :uid
        and care.quarter = :quarter
        and care.year = :year
        and care.clientAccountNo = relationship.clientAccountNo
```

HQL and associations are well described in [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). Read it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it!